# Android: Incomplete overwriting of text file

Tags: android, file, text, overwrite

My phone runs Android 4.0.4 and is in Media Transfer Protocol (MTP) mode.  My app is attempting to overwrite the same text file on the phone’s SD card with progressing larger files, using successive calls of the following code:

```
File mDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Location");
File mFile = new File(mDir, "Location.txt");
PrintWriter mPW = new PrintWriter(mFile);
mPW.println(sData);  // sData is a string of a few hundred characters
mPW.flush();
mPW.close();
```

During testing in USB debugging mode, I had the following problem.  In Windows 7, I could open a file written with the latest data, but the Date modified’s time and Size corresponded to an earlier write of the file and I could only see as many characters as corresponded to that size.  Effectively new data in an old file.

I scoured the Web but no one seems to have reported this sort of problem.  I tried lots of fancier ways of writing the file, including using buffered classes and even deleting and recreating the file before re-writing it, all to no avail.

After re-booting the phone, the problem seems to have gone away, but I wonder if this rings a bell with anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is published via the MTP interface is what the `MediaStore` knows about the file. The `MediaStore` will eventually pick up your changes, faster if you use something like `MediaScannerConnection` to proactively tell it that the file has changed.

However, what MTP *clients* choose to do is up to them. In general, they seem to cache results, and I am not aware of whether MTP has any sort of "push" semantics to tell the MTP client "hey, something you asked for a bit ago has changed". Some might reload contents based upon a "reload" or "refresh" option in the MTP client UI. Others might assume the contents are unchanging, until such time as the device is unplugged and re-plugged in.

In general, I would not advocate your approach (continuously appending to the same file, with the user expecting to be able to see those changes in real time), simply due to the apparent limitations of MTP.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, @CommonsWare.  Fortunately, I was only relying on MTP for simplicity during development, as the user will access the file remotely via Airdroid or similar.

Opinions seem to vary about whether USB debugging is equally happy with MTP or MSC.

Comment: @user3787658: If by MSC you mean USB Mass Storage, that was used for Android 1.x/2.x. Then, you wouldn't have the ability to write to the file at all while it was mounted as a drive on a host computer. MTP at least allows simultaneous access, albeit with limitations.

Comment: Yes, I meant USB **m**ass **s**torage device **c**lass. Thanks for pointing out that USB Mass Storage wouldn't really speed up development.

Now I know that the problem is simply one of visibility, I can stop worrying about it.

BTW, I was already using an SD re-scanner app to try to improve the sync, but I usually end up also having to unplug and replug the USB cable!

Comment: @user3787658: Another option you could consider is to embed a tiny Web server in your app that serves up the file. I get nervous about these in production code, but for development, it's more reasonable. You could even have some static "wrapper" page that does timed reloads of the generated content, to save you having to reload the Web browser.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to avoid "expensive" services such as www.noip.com, but a web server for development makes a lot of sense.